# Can I use a parent function's parameter to name its child function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have a parent function with a single parameter. 
I want to use this parameter in the naming of a couple child functions. 
Can this be done?

```
function A(red) {
    function redBall() {
        stuff
    }
    function redHat() {
        stuff
    }
}
```

This is a more specific example of what I am trying to create.
I would run this function many times, which is why I need the child functions to have unique names based on the parameter provided.

```
function name(parameter) {

    let parameterThis = '"' + parameter + 'This"';
    let parameterThat = '"' + parameter + 'That"';
    let $button = '$(".button.' + parameter + '")';

    function parameterEnter() {
        document.getElementById(parameterThis).style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById(parameterThat).style.display = "block";
    }

    function parameterLeave() {
        document.getElementById(parameterThis).style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById(parameterThat).style.display = "none";
    }

    $button.hover(parameterEnter,parameterLeave);
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't allow creation on functions inside functions.

Comment: Perhaps the tag should be Javascript?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve? And why is your `$button` just a string that contains a jQuery call? :)
Other than that, your code should work fine

Comment: I need the child function names to be given by the parameter. In the above example, if I run name(A), it should run child functions AEnter() and ALeave(). name(B) should run BEnter() and BLeave(). As for the $button, if there's something wrong with that, I'm too inexperienced to tell.

Comment: Kinda pointless to make guesses as to what button does what to what element when hovered over that whatever that is according to who the hell knows why there's dimensions for something. Please post HTML.

Comment: I don't think that's really necessary to answer my question. Just need to know if there's a way to use the parameter I provide to name child functions.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: renaming functions isn't what you really want.

You don't need to make your functions named differently for it to work. That's not how programming is supposed to work. Instead, try to generalize what you're trying to do, so that it can be applied to whatever you pass in. Like, if you need it to do different things in certain cases, add another parameter to the function. Or, if you need unique things to happen for each element, make your function take enter/leave callback functions as arguments. Even if you did programmatically set the function names, you'd have a hard time calling them anyways, because you wouldn't know what they were called.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
functionA (boolean condition)
{
    if (condition)
         fonctionB();
    else
         fonctionC();
}

functionB()
{
    // Stuff
}

functionC()
{
    // Stuff
}
```

If what you intend to do is to actually declare a function or another depending of a parameter, I don't think that's possible. But I don't really get why you would want to do that, and perhaps we could help you better if you were more accurate on that matter.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up my code. When elements of a certain CSS class are hovered, multiple other elements of specified ID are affected. I've already achieved the intended effect, but I'm sure it can be accomplished with much less code.

Comment: I have additional functions for when the mouse leaves the elements and when they are clicked. So it's messy.

Comment: You could make a new MouseListener (or whatever) abstract class or interface, often helps reducing code redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, maybe simpler than passing arguments?

```
var foo = function() {
    this.a = function () {
        console.log('A function');
    }

    this.b = function() {
        console.log('B function');
    }
    return this;
}
```

Then call function you want like this for example

```
foo().a();
```

**EDIT:**
  I missunderstood your code, If I understand correctly now, you want to pass purely a string and then call function with such name immediately?
Well, you can do it using `eval()` but many people advise to stay away from using it, anywhere here it is:

```
function foo(whatFunction) {
    function a() {
        console.log('a function');
    }

    function b() {
        console.log('b function')
    }
    eval(whatFunction)();
}
```

So then call it `foo('b')` for example

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer to my actual question is no, judging by how everyone has responded. 
I'll have to keep thinking on it and find another way to simplify my code.